# wordnet getDict() could not find Wordnet dictionary

Tags: r, wordnet

when using the following code to use the Lemmatizer algorithm from WordNet

```
> initDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
[1] TRUE

if(initDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict"))
    getDict()
```

I have the following error when trying to get the dictionary:

```
Error in getDict() : could not find Wordnet dictionary
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `setDict` of use for setting the location?

Comment: No, but I've just added and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the package is looking for the environment variable WNHOME

Try this:

```
>     setDict("C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/dict")
```

-

> ```
> getDict()
> [1] "Java-Object{com.nexagis.jawbone.Dictionary@46993aaa}"
> ```

**EDIT**

Adding OSX version

```
brew install wordnet

install.packages('wordnet')
library(wordnet)
setDict("/usr/local/Cellar/wordnet/3.1")
initDict()
getDict()
```