# Getting synonyms using wordnet in latest version of R

Tags: r

I try to find synonyms using wordnet package in the latest version of R.

I have downloaded the wordnet file and here are the following action with the errors:

```
> library(wordnet)
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
> initDict("C:/Users/iris/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/WordNet-3.0/dict")
[1] TRUE
> library(wordnet)
> Str = synonyms("help")
Error in charmatch(x, WN_synset_types) : 
  argument "pos" is missing, with no default
> synonyms("company", "NOUN")
Error in getDict() : could not find Wordnet dictionary
> getDict("C:/Users/iris/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/WordNet-3.0/dict")
Error in getDict("C:/Users/iris/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/WordNet-3.0/dict") : 
  unused argument ("C:/Users/iris/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/WordNet-3.0/dict")
```

Is there any general problem with wordnet package in R?

or

```
library(wordnet)
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
> initDict()
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
> setDict("C:/Users/iris/Downloads/WordNet-3.0/WordNet-3.0/dict")
> getDict()
[1] "Java-Object{com.nexagis.jawbone.Dictionary@1540e19d}"
> initDict()
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In initDict() :
  cannot find WordNet 'dict' directory: please set the environment variable WNHOME to its parent
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordnet getDict() could not find Wordnet dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129073/wordnet-getdict-could-not-find-wordnet-dictionary)

Comment: @Fernando thank you for your comment. I have some of the steps of the answer in my question and also I tried the steps from the answer from the link you provide but again there are errors. Can you run the wordnet successfuly?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me (with Sys.setenv(WNHOME... and without initDict()):

```
library(wordnet)
Sys.setenv(WNHOME ="C:/<windows path>/WordNet-3.0/dict")
setDict("C:/<windows path>/WordNet-3.0/dict")
synonyms("car","NOUN")

[1] "auto"         "automobile"   "cable car"    "car"          "elevator car" "gondola"     
[7] "machine"      "motorcar"     "railcar"      "railroad car" "railway car"
```